# Android Acitity in Finishing State, Can not show AlertDialog,Why

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

These are two Activity,say ActivityA and ActivityB , when click a button in ActivityA ,ActivityB will be launched,click "return" button in AcitivityB,in the button handler activity.finish is called
. again click the button in ActivityA, ActivityB is launched again,but i found **ActivityB.this.isfinishing returns true**. so I can not update the TextField values. Why?

well, in In ActivityB, start a long time Task in background ,when the the task finished ,in the UI thread ,an AlertDialog is created and shown,the second time, this AlertDialog no shown because the Activity.this.isfinishing return's true. so why the second time,start the ActiviyB ,calling this.sifinishing return true.seemd this ActivityB.this is the first time created.(this first created ActivityB is fininished by calling finish()).

Comment: Could you explain more about the problem? You mentioned `AlertDialog` on the title, but you wrote about text field (`EditText`?) in the description. Also, what are you trying to do? Perhaps it can be done by overriding one of activity's lifecycle (e.g: `onDestroy()`)

Comment: well, in In ActivityB, start a long time Task in background ,when the the task finished ,in the UI thread ,an AlertDialog is created and shown,the second time, this AlertDialog no shown because the Activity.this.isfinishing return's true. so why the second time,start the ActiviyB ,calling this.sifinishing return true.seemd this ActivityB.this is the first time created.(this first created ActivityB is fininished by calling finish()).